# iOS: Is it possible to launch an update in background of an app when iPad is in standby mode (when user has pressed the power button quickly)?

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, push-notification, uilocalnotification

I have a piece of code that allows me to update my app at a specific time:

**MainViewController.m:**

```
NSDate *now = [NSDate date];
    NSCalendar *calendar = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSCalendarIdentifierGregorian];
    NSDateComponents *components = [calendar components:NSCalendarUnitYear|NSCalendarUnitMonth|NSCalendarUnitDay fromDate:now];
    [components setHour:14];
    [components setMinute:5];
    [components setSecond:0];
    NSDate *nextAlarm = [calendar dateFromComponents:components];
    if ([nextAlarm timeIntervalSinceNow] < 0)
    {
        nextAlarm = [nextAlarm dateByAddingTimeInterval:60*60*24];
    }
    UILocalNotification *localNotification = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
    [localNotification setRepeatInterval: NSCalendarUnitDay];
    [localNotification setFireDate:nextAlarm];
    [localNotification setAlertBody:@"It's been one day"];
    [localNotification setValue:nextAlarm forKey:@"fireDate"];

    UIApplication *app = [UIApplication sharedApplication];
    [app scheduleLocalNotification:localNotification];
```

**AppDelegate.m**

```
  NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter=[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"];
    NSDate *synchroDate = notification.fireDate;

    NSDate *currentDate= [NSDate date];
    NSLog(@"difference : %f", [synchroDate timeIntervalSinceDate:currentDate]);

    NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
    NSInteger comps = (NSCalendarUnitDay | NSCalendarUnitMonth | NSCalendarUnitYear | NSCalendarUnitHour | NSCalendarUnitMinute);

    NSDateComponents *date1Components = [calendar components:comps
                                                    fromDate: currentDate];
    NSDateComponents *date2Components = [calendar components:comps
                                                    fromDate: synchroDate];

    currentDate = [calendar dateFromComponents:date1Components];
    synchroDate = [calendar dateFromComponents:date2Components];

    BOOL result = [currentDate isEqual:synchroDate];

    if (result)
    {
        [self autoSynchro];
    }
```

My problem is that I would like that code be launched when my device is off. I can see that the notification is well launched on the ipad main screen, but the function is not launched...
[image]

May be I have to use that:

```
UIApplicationState state = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] applicationState];
if (state == UIApplicationStateInactive)
{
   //Do checking here.
}
```

But how to launch it if it is in standby mode?
Any ideas?

Comment: I presume you mean when your app is in the background, not when the iPad is off. When it is off it can't do anything. You can use background refresh but you can't schedule it for a specific time.

Comment: @Paulw11 I mean when the ipad is not noff, but just in standby mode with the black screen. I can see the notification make the ipad going out of the standby mode. Is it possible during that to launch a function in background?

Comment: No, it isn't possible